# In Android: Can I receive a Broadcast intent from one application into second application

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an application `Application1` which contains 2 java classes `Sender` (for sending a Broadcast intent) and `Receiver` (for receiving the Broadcast intent broadcasted by `Sender`).

So can I receive the intent broadcasted by `Sender` of `Application1` in a `Receiver` class of an other application, let suppose `Applications2`? Is it possible to receive the intent broadcasted by one application into an other application?

Answer (score 2):

the answer is - yes, you can. `BroadcastReceiver` is the right (and only trivial) way passing data between applications. no problem broadcasting intent from application1 and receive it with the appropriate intent filter in application2. furthermore - Google recommends doing so.
one thing you need to know - your intent filter should be unique, and not easy to guess by malicious apps want to intercept some private user's data you don't want to share with them.

Comment: Then how to do so. I have registered a receiver in Application1's Manifest file with Intent-Filter and action, then I should use that action in Application2's java code?

Comment: yes. that what you need to do if you want to send broadcast to application1 from application2.  you tried to do that and it didn't worked?

Comment: Actually I am broadcasting from Application1 and receiving in Application2 and did not work

Comment: I have also registered a receiver in Application2's Manifest file with the same action that was given in Application1's broadcasted Intent.

Comment: so application1 sending the broadcast from java code, and application2 register in the manifest with the receiver.   anyway - post your relevant code. I'll have a look

Comment: I have written this code in my Sender java file of Application1

Intent intent = new Intent("example.test.MYBROADCAST");
intent.putExtra("msg", "My message");
sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: @swdeveloper: that's looks ok.  now let's see application2 implementation of receiver, and manifest.  did your receiver declaration in the manifest is under specific activity?

Comment: And I am receiving that Broadcasted intent in Receiver (in Application1) which is registered in Manifest (of Application1) with action "example.test.MYBROADCAST" and it works fine. But I want to receive in Application2's Receiver, which is registered in Application2's Manifest with action "example.test.MYBROADCAST" and it does not work

Comment: @swdeveloper: I need to see the whole manifest, and the whole receiver implementation.  because from what you are saying - everything should work

Comment: This is App1's Manifest

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".MyBroadcastSender">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.test.MYBROADCAST"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>

Comment: This is application2's Manifest

<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    
        <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.test.MYBROADCAST"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
</application>

Comment: Actually I am receiving in both, Application1's MyBroadcastReceiver java file (which work fine) and Application2's Receiver java file (which does not work)

Comment: @swdeveloper: your application2 implemts class called - Receiver, which is inside package name with the same name of your application's package name?

Comment: No the package name of Application2's class is different

Comment: @swdeveloper: I have to go now.  from all what you wrote - it suppose to work if class Receiver is inside package name with the same package name of your applications package name.   anyway - I don't understand why you asked that question - you are saying that you succeed sending from first application to second application, but did not succeed sending from second to first.  so you know it's possible

Comment: @swdeveloper: if the package name of the application is diffrent - that's explains why it doesn't work.  don't write ".Receive", but the whole pakage: name="com.my.class.package.Receiver"

Comment: Please last question: Should the package name in both applications must be the same ?

Comment: @swdeveloper: no, they don't.  the only thing must be the same is the action name (intent filter string name..). please give me some credit for my help :)

Comment: I am trying to figure out. A lots of thanks for your suggestions. Thank you so much.